# Python Create a VPN connection for just a host

Tags: python, sockets, connection, vpn

I want to create a VPN connection with a Python script for just a few Python sockets. I need to tunnel just the traffic of that script through a VPN like a Proxy does it.
Is there any API?

I cannot change the setting of the machine because the user may not want to create a VPN which tunnels his traffic.

Comment: This might be a good situation to use a ssh tunnel.

Comment: I'm looking for a python script for vpn connection too

Answer (score 3):

What you want is not a VPN, is an IP port forward, a proxy:

http://voorloopnul.com/blog/a-python-proxy-in-less-than-100-lines-of-code/

If need a secure connection between 2 hosts you could use a SSH port forward:

http://www.debianadmin.com/howto-use-ssh-local-and-remote-port-forwarding.html

Comment: I know that I need a Proxy. The only problem I have is that the server I use only supports common VPN protocols such as PPTP, OpenVPN, and L2PT. Is there a way to use one of these protocols as a "Proxy"? So I need a little hack... Btw: I can't install anything on the server because it is not mine.